# Why is a forward declaration in a class not a forward declaration to an inner class? C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, forward-declaration

My question is;
Why is a forward declaration in a class not a forward declaration to an inner class? Is it defined or undefined?
There is no purpose, i only wondered, why it is so.

Example;

```
class A
{
public:
  class B *b;

  class B
  {
  };
};

class B
{
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    A::B ab;

    a.b = &b;  //OK
    a.b = &ab; //Doesn't compile (godbolt.org)

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
Thanks all. If somebody wonder for namespaces, there is the code.

```
namespace A
{
  class B *pb;

  /*class B;
  B pb;*/ //It is the same as above. But has another meaning in class

  class B
  {
  };
}

class B
{
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A::B ab;

    A::pb = &b;  //Never compiles
    A::pb = &ab; //OK

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @dyukha The question is why `class B *b;` refers to the `B` outside of `A` (which does not appear to be in the same scope), not the nested class (which appears to be in the same scope).

Comment: `class B;` is a proper forward declaration, and it does what you expect. But yeah, this seems like a little inconsistency in the language at the first sight.

Comment: Isn't it even more surprising that declaring a field with previously unseen type also acts as a forward declaration of that type?

Comment: @geza yes it seems inconsistent. what about different namespaces? i hope that it is consistent for different namespaces. i mean it is a forward declaration for a class in the same namespace, or am i wrong?

Comment: FWIW, forward declarations of classes within classes _are_ forward declarations of inner classes: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.nest#3. It appears that `class B *b;` behaves differently from that though.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `class B *b;` is a forward declaration of `class B` from outer scope.

Comment: @YusufR.Karagöz: "it is a forward declaration for a class in the same namespace". Yes.

Comment: Btw., I've checked, and as it seems, the standard doesn't define what a forward declaration is. It uses this term several places, but doesn't define it. So, whether we consider `class B *b;` (in class scope) as a forward declaration, is subjective. It declares `B`, sure. But as it declares it in an "unexpected" scope, we may not consider it forward declaration.